# How is there a memory leak in this simple code?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

This function was working fine and not sure what changed but seems there is a memory leak now.

```
# This list has about 500 entries
basic_materials = ['CADC', 'AA', 'AAU', ... ,'ZKIN', 'ZN']

def basic_materials_sector_order():

    sector_basic_materials = basic_materials
    main_df = pd.DataFrame()    

    for count,ticker in enumerate(sector_basic_materials):
        df = pd.read_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
        df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

        df.rename(columns = {'Adj Close':ticker}, inplace=True)
        df.drop(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'], 1, inplace=True)

        if main_df.empty:
            main_df = df
        else:
            main_df = main_df.join(df, how='outer')

    main_df.to_csv('sector_dfs/basic_materials.csv')
```

This code just takes stock price data, drops all columns except the close, then joins these closes into a new CSV file. The list size isn't the problem.

There must be a reference cycle here because this starts fast and slows down massively. I don't know. Any advice or help is very much appreciated!

Comment: you really should not give a variable and a function the same name on same scope level

Comment: this was just for purpose of the example. In reality the function is basic_materials_sector_order():

Comment: ok, then - rename it to avoid confusion

Comment: it will read 500 csv files and join them into a dataframe synchronously. It can obviously bring a performance hit.

Comment: I understand that. Earlier though it was working fine reading that many CSV. Any way to make this process faster?

Comment: maybe, those csv files got bigger in size. Anyway, is the order of merging those csv data matters?

Comment: They haven't gotten bigger. The order does not matter at all

Comment: The point is that memory leak (as your title tells) is not directly correlated with time delays: you may speed up the processing but at the end get a similar memory leak. Measure memory consumption on each loop iteration to see the tendency (perhaps `resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss`)

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a memory leak but it starts off fast and then slows down dramatically, though doesn't seem to trigger a memory error. Where would I put in resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss

Comment: right after your `if/else` block, don't forget to `print()` the memory stats

Comment: Apparently I'm unable to run this on windows 10. Is it possible that the CSV files aren't closing after the loops?

Comment: I changed the list into a tuple and its alot faster though still slows down considerably quite quickly.

Comment: I would solve this issue, but I don't like Windows and its conditions

Comment: What lol? You don't think its fixable on Windows?

Comment: Rather than loading the whole CSV file in and then dropping the unwanted columns, you could investigate the `usecols` option. This would also reduce your memory requirements.